# Get Email To Receiver When Submitted And Also Sender Get Submission Copy using PHPMailer

Tags: php, forms, email, phpmailer

I am newbie with PHPMailer library , I want to get emails from my contact form  But on submission of form I want sender  also get a copy of mail With additional message as " thanks for registering with us." As I gone through PHP mailer examples We can use **addCC();**. But how to embed additional msg.

Could you please help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CC or BCC will always result in identical message being sent to all; If you want the messages to be different for different recipients, you must send separate messages with different bodies. With PHPMailer:

```
$mail->addAddress('recipient1@example.com');
$mail->Body = "hello abc";
$mail->send();
$mail->clearAddresses();
$mail->addAddress('recipient2@example.com');
$mail->Body = "hello xyz";
$mail->send();
```

It's important to call `clearAddresses` as otherwise the second message will be sent to both recpients.