# Sending mail to both sender and receiver using PHPmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using phpmailer in live server for sending emails for both sender and receiver. Its working fine but I want to include additional message in sender copy  as "thanks for registering with us". I am unable to do it.
Could you please help with this ? 
Code I tried So far:

```
<?php
$msg = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    function sendemail($to, $from, $fromName, $body) {
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->setFrom($from, $fromName);
        $mail->addAddress($to);

        $mail->Subject = 'Contact Form - Email';
        $mail->Body = $body;
        $mail->isHTML(false);
        return $mail->send();
    }
    function sender_mail($to, $from, $fromName, $body) {
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->setFrom($from, $fromName);
        $mail->addAddress($to);

        $mail->Subject = 'Copy Contact Form - Email';
        $mail->Body = $body . 'Thanks for registering with us';
        $mail->isHTML(false);

        return $mail->send();
    }
    $name = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $body = $_POST['body'];
   sendemail('abc@domain.com', 'xyz@domain.com', $name, $body);
    sender_mail('abc@domain.com', $email, $name, $body);  
}?>
```

Comment: Have you tried with my solution by adding another object of PHPMailer

Comment: Is this homework? It's identical to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47632040), which already has an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always create different mail object for sending another email. So it will always pick new message.

For sending another email you can update like below:

```
    $mail2 = new PHPMailer();
    $mail2->setFrom($from, $fromName);
    $mail2->addAddress($to);

    $mail2->Subject = 'Copy Contact Form - Email';
    $mail2->Body = $body . 'Thanks for registering with us';
    $mail2->isHTML(false);

    return $mail2->send();
```

2nd option to use `clearAddresses` above your second email to clear your earlier messages like below:

```
    $mail->clearAddresses();

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->setFrom($from, $fromName);
    $mail->addAddress($to);

    $mail->Subject = 'Copy Contact Form - Email';
    $mail->Body = $body . 'Thanks for registering with us';
    $mail->isHTML(false);

    return $mail->send();
```

Comment: @ Amit Gupta Thanks a lot  Problem has been resolved

Comment: That's a waste of resources. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47632040/333340) for a more efficient approach.

Comment: @Synchro Yes you are right but what if the body and subject is different for both emails. Can we repeat $mail->Body for 2 emails with different message in same Page?

Comment: Yes - my example shows using a different `Body` for each message, but you can equally change the `Subject` too.

Comment: Ok I got it. You have added $mail->clearAddresses(); to clear the earlier messages. Great job. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: It's important to call clearAddresses as otherwise the second message will be sent to both recpients. Right Sir.

Comment: @SowmyaS Please accept my answer if your issue has been resolved. You will also get 2 points. Happy Coding :)